# How to remove onclick and insert rel="lightbox" with javascript (magento go)

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, onclick, lightbox2

I'm working with a magento go (SaaS) store and need to remove onclick, insert rel="lightbox" as well as change the href="#" to the img src url. Any help appreciated. Can javascript or jQuery do that? I can only play around with javascript as I cannot access the application codes.

```
<div class="more-views">
<h2>More Views</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="popWin('http://101pareos.com.au/catalog/product/gallery/id/49/image/81/', 'gallery', 'width=300,height=300,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false;" title="Image 1">
                        <img src="http://s4f7e756057ed2.img.gostorego.com/802754/cdn/media/s4/f7/e7/56/05/7e/d2/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/48x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b016.jpg" width="48" height="48" alt="Image 1" />
                    </a>
    </li>          
</div>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voilà:

```
$('.more-views a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var image = $this.find('img');

    $this.attr({
        onclick: null,
        href: image.attr('src'),
        rel: 'lightbox'
    });
});
```

EDIT: To extract the URL, all you have to do is:

```
jQuery('.more-views a').each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    $this.attr({
        onclick: null,
        href: /'(.+?)'/.exec($this.attr('onclick'))[1],
        rel: 'lightbox'
    });
});
```

EDIT: To extract the image, it's a little (okay, a lot) more complicated.

```
jQuery('.more-views a').each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: /'(.+?)'/.exec($this.attr('onclick'))[1],
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            // Extract the image from the HTML:
            var url = /img src="(.+?)"/.exec(data)[1];

            // Set the new href, remove the old onclick handler, and make it a lightbox:
            $this.attr({
                onclick: null,
                href: url,
                rel: 'lightbox'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: if onclick:null won't work try to jQuery('...').unbind('click');

Comment: Wow! Quick reply! Looks good but it didn't work. Any idea why it didn't change any of the attributes? Site is here [link]http://101pareos.com.au/batik-pareos/baby-blue-floral.html

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov: No, I tried `unbind` and it *really* doesn't work.

Comment: @ryanwkan: You got Prototype in my jQuery! Change the first `$` and `$(this)` to `jQuery` and `jQuery(this)`, respectively, and it should work.

Comment: @minitech It works!

I just opened up a new can of worms though...

Looks like the thumbnail image URL is scaled down by the system. Is it possible for jquery to dive into the popwin url and pick out the image URL from there?

[link]<a href="#" onclick="popWin('http://101pareos.com.au/catalog/product/gallery/id/41/image/50/'

opens up a new window in which the larger image URL reside.

Is it technically possible to dive into there and grab the URL, then append to the href above?

Comment: @ryanwkan: Yes it is! I'll add that.

Comment: @minitech It's almost there! The href part of the code has gone to a level beyond my comprehension, but I tried it and it links to the popwin URL but I actually want the url to be the URL of the image in the popup. If it helps, the image in the popwin URL have an ID of "product-gallery-image".

The exact structure of the popwin URL is here if it helps:
[link]http://101pareos.com.au/catalog/product/gallery/id/56/image/112/

Comment: @ryanwkan: So, to clarify; you want this image? http://s4f7e756057ed2.img.gostorego.com/802754/cdn/media/s4/f7/e7/56/05/7e/d2/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/batik_pareo_size.png

Comment: @ryanwkan: Okay! That'll take some Ajax then. Hold on. In the meantime, do something else, because it'll be a while :)

Comment: @minitech Take your time! You're awesome!

Comment: @ryanwkan: Okay, sorry for the wait, I've updated my answer with the Ajax version.

Comment: @minitech WOW! You're the best! Thanks again for helping me out! It works like a champ!